# what's the time cost of Swapping 2 values of 2 variables in a list(with n variables); python

Tags: python, time

```
# nums = a list with n variables
i = 0
j = len(nums) - 1
while i < j:
    nums[i], nums[j] = nums[j], nums[i]
    i += 1
    j -= 1
```

I want to know the total time cost of those actions, is O(n)?

Comment: Yes it is. The loop count is n/2, so time complexity is O(n). By the way, you can perform it with builtin function `reversed`.

Comment: thanks :) recently I learnt about data structure, I want to understand the internal mechanism of different operations on data structure, like List, Dict, Tuple

Comment: Here is concept of data structures: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types. And if you want learn about internal logic, I think you should see CPython's code. Because some internal algorithms depend on implementation of interpreters.